# How to search for methods that return a List of a specific class in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I found the Java search in eclipse takes a specific pattern so that you can search on the declaring type name, the method name, the argument types, and the return type. This is how it's presented in the help documents:

> Method patterns have the following syntax:
>
> **[declaringType '.'] ['<' typeArguments '>'] methodName ['(' parameterTypes ')'] [returnType]**
>
> Type arguments have the same syntax as explained in the type patterns section.
>
> Examples:
>
> - `java.lang.Runnable.run() void`
> - `main(*)`
> - `<String>toArray(String[])`

I wanted to find all methods that returned `List<MyClass>`, so I constructed what I thought would be the right pattern for the method search: `* List<MyClass>`. But this matched all methods that returned a `List` of any type.

I've also tried the "Type Search" and limiting the "Match Locations" to "Method return types", but I get the same problem, all `List`s are returned, not just lists of my type.

Comment: Looks like it might be a bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=350566

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with Eclipse IDE. As a workaround you can use the same pattern under File search tab with file pattern as *.java. The problem with this way is that you will be able to search only in source under workspace/workingset but not in libraries

Comment: Yeah, but with File Search I can't restrict it to just the return types of java methods right? Unless I come up with some complicated (possibly multi-line) regex for matching java methods, right? Oh, and did you verify that this doesn't work for you either?